# How to implement multiple route with single container or layout in react-router-dom v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to know how can I implement multiple route with single container or layout in react-router-dom v6

Here is my code so far:

```
<Routes>
<Route
        path="/dashboard"
        element={
          <AdminLayout>
            <DashboardScreen />
          </AdminLayout>
        }
      />
      <Route
        path="/guides"
        element={
          <AdminLayout>
            <GuidesScreen />
          </AdminLayout>
        }
      />
      <Route
        path="/post"
        element={
          <AdminLayout>
            <PostScreen />
          </AdminLayout>
        }
      />
</Routes>
```

But it's not working, What Am I missing here?

Thanks!

Code Update:

```
<Routes>
    <LoginLayout>
      <Route path="/" element={<SignInForm />} />
      <Route path="/signin" element={<SignInForm />} />
      <Route path="/newpassword" element={<NewPassword />} />
      <Route path="/phoneverification" element={<PhoneVerification />} />
      <Route path="/continuewithphone" element={<ContWithPhone />} />
      <Route path="/resetpassword" element={<ResetPassword />} />
      <Route
        path="/confirm-resetpassword"
        element={<ConfirmResetPassword />}
      />
    </LoginLayout>
  </Routes>
  <Routes>
    <AdminLayout>
      //Routes here
    </AdminLayout>
  </Routes>
```

Sample Console warnings:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you've "common" layout containers you want to share/render with multiple routes/routed components then it's common to have each layout render nested routes into an `Outlet` component.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const LoginLayout = () => (
  <div /* layout props & styling */ >
    {/* local layout UI */}
    <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes rendered here
  </div>
);

const AdminLayout = () => (
  <div /* layout props & styling */ >
    {/* local layout UI */}
    <Outlet />
  </div>
);
```

...

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<LoginLayout />}>
    <Route path="/" element={<SignInForm />} />
    <Route path="/signin" element={<SignInForm />} />
    <Route path="/newpassword" element={<NewPassword />} />
    <Route path="/phoneverification" element={<PhoneVerification />} />
    <Route path="/continuewithphone" element={<ContWithPhone />} />
    <Route path="/resetpassword" element={<ResetPassword />} />
    <Route
      path="/confirm-resetpassword"
      element={<ConfirmResetPassword />}
    />
  </Route>
  <Route element={<AdminLayout />}>
    // Routes here
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Comment: Hi Sir, its working fine but I just checked the console log, it show warning no routes matched location "mypath"..

Comment: @CoffeeCode I don't see any `"/mypath"` path in your code example. Can you clarify what this issue is here?

Comment: Hi Sir, I Added screenshot in my question..warnings is displayed when I click the navlinks. Thanks

Comment: @CoffeeCode Did you remember to add the `Outlet` component to your layout containers for the nested routes to be rendered into?

Answer (score 11):

There are several approaches you can choose with react-router@6.

The first option is to pass routes as children to a layout component.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
    
    const AdminLayout = ({ children }) => (
        <div>
            <nav>
                <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/dashboard">Dashboard</NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/guides">Guides</NavLink>
            </nav>
            <div>
                {children}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
    
    const Home = () => (<span>Home</span>);
    const Dashboard = () => (<span>Dashboard</span>);
    const Guides = () => (<span>Guides</span>);
    
    const App = () => {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <AdminLayout>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
                        <Route path="/guides" element={<Guides />} />
                    </Routes>
                </AdminLayout>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    };
            
    export default App;
```

The second option is to use `<Outlet>` component. There's an [example](https://stackblitz.com/github/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/basic?file=src/App.tsx) from the react-router@6 docs.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, NavLink, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
    
    const AdminLayout = () => (
        <div>
            <nav>
                <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/dashboard">Dashboard</NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/guides">Guides</NavLink>
            </nav>
            <div>
                <Outlet />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
    
    const Home = () => (<span>Home</span>);
    const Dashboard = () => (<span>Dashboard</span>);
    const Guides = () => (<span>Guides</span>);
    
    const App = () => {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<AdminLayout />}>
                        <Route index element={<Home />} />
                        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
                        <Route path="/guides" element={<Guides />} />
                    </Route>
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    };
            
    export default App;
```

---

**EDITED:**
Multiple routed with multiple layouts can be done by using `<Outlet>` component in layouts and `<Route>` component composition.
`<Routes>` component is similar to react-router@5 Switch: [docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route).

Here's an example how to you can use multiple layouts with multiple routes:

```
    const AdminLayout = () => (
        <div>
            <h1>Admin Lyout</h1>
            <Outlet />
        </div>
    );
    
    const LoginLayout = () => (
        <div>
            <h1>Login Layout</h1>
            <Outlet />
        </div>
    );
    
    const Home = () => (<span>Home</span>);
    const Dashboard = () => (<span>Dashboard</span>);
    const SignInForm = () => (<span>SignInForm</span>);
    const NewPassword  = () => (<span>NewPassword </span>);
    
    const App = () => {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <nav>
                    <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
                    <NavLink to="/dashboard">Dashboard</NavLink>
                    <NavLink to="/login">SignInForm</NavLink>
                    <NavLink to="/new-password">NewPassword</NavLink>
                </nav>
                <Routes>
                    <Route element={<LoginLayout />}>
                        <Route path="/login" element={<SignInForm />} />
                        <Route path="/new-password" element={<NewPassword />} />
                    </Route>
                    <Route element={<AdminLayout />}>
                        <Route index element={<Home />} />
                        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
                    </Route>
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    };
```

Comment: Hi Sir @eugenezinovyev, I updated my question. What If i have multiple layouts? how can I switch? already tried something in my updated code but gives me error Error: [LoginLayout] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

Comment: @CoffeeCode here's an example how you can use multiple layouts in the updaed answer